# AppFabric 1.1 How Many DataCacheServerEndpoint's Should Client Connect To?

Tags: iis-7, appfabric-cache

The AppFabric 1.1 client documentation discusses assigning a list of DataCachServer endpoints to the DataCacheFactoryConfiguration. Most of the examples show the list consisting of a single or perhaps two different cache servers. If the cluster consists of *n* servers should the client register each of the servers?  Does it matter what order the servers are registered in?  For example, if I have 50 servers in my web tier, and 5 servers in my cache tier, do each of the 50 web servers register all 5 caching servers?  Here is sample code:

```
// Declare array for cache host(s).
DataCacheServerEndpoint[] servers = new DataCacheServerEndpoint[5];
servers[0] = new DataCacheServerEndpoint("Cache01", 22233);
servers[1] = new DataCacheServerEndpoint("Cache02", 22233);
servers[2] = new DataCacheServerEndpoint("Cache03", 22233);
servers[3] = new DataCacheServerEndpoint("Cache04", 22233);
servers[4] = new DataCacheServerEndpoint("Cache05", 22233);

// Setup the DataCacheFactory configuration.
DataCacheFactoryConfiguration factoryConfig = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
factoryConfig.Servers = servers;

// Create a configured DataCacheFactory object.
DataCacheFactory mycacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory(factoryConfig);

// Get a cache client for the cache named "default".
DataCache myDefaultCache = mycacheFactory.GetCache("default");
```

Can each web server register identically, and will the load be balanced across the caching tier? If a registered server becomes unavailable is the next one tried in sequence, or is it randomized? Links to supporting documentation would be helpful.

Related to load balancing, [Jason Roth](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/velocity/thread/ac04a2af-a850-4fea-836a-f3377f2bfa55) wrote the following [is there other documentation available]?

> App fabric client is smart client and it can directly contact the server which ever server has your data. The application need not worry about load balancing. This is done using the routing client.

Answer (score 1):

Based on some testing, and letting Jason Roth's comment sink in, I *think* the DataCacheServerEndPoint is used by the "smart client" to retrieve the list of cache cluster members when the GetCache method is called on the DataCacheFactory.  The DataCache object is the thing that is smart--and it is smart in the sense that if the server used in the DataCacheServerEndpoint instantiation goes offline or otherwise becomes unavailable, the smart client still has access to the other cluster members.  Therefore the purpose of a list of more than one DataCacheServerEndpoint is to provide redundancy when calling the GetCache method.

The advice is that the DataCache object should follow a singleton pattern, and not be instantiated on each request for data from the cache.  Which is why there is no need to loadbalance or provide a VIP for the individual DataCacheServerEndpoints.

Instantiate as many DataCacheServerEndPoints as needed to ensure at least one is up at all times--there is no need to add every member of the cache cluster unless that is the only way to ensure at least one is up.

When it comes to administering boxes in the cache cluster (for instance, applying monthly patches), consider minimizing the cache thrashing and rebalancing by administering a single box at a time, rather than attempting to administer groups of boxes in "waves".